# Suggestions for Dashboard/ Database Reporting software

Tags: mysql, dashboard, dashboard-designer

We are looking for a reporting suite that will allow us to analyse our data. I'm not sure of the exact terminology for such suites but they are often known as 'Dashboard Software' or 'Database Reporting'

An example is: [Wonder Graphs](http://www.wondergraphs.com/)

We are looking for a suite that will integrate with our MySQL database and provide us with:

- 'Live' graphical Interfaces (Graphs, Charts) for viewing our data which are automatically updated
- The ability to 'Drill Down' using these charts to see more specific information.

For example if a chart shows total sales, we want to be able to click on that graph and be shown information on type of sales.

- The ability to export to excel
- An easy-to-use user interface that allows non-technical users to create and customise their own views or dashboards.

If anyone can list software they use, have used, or know to be good that would be a great help.

If there is an open-source example available that is great however we are expecting to pay for such software.

Let me know if I have been to vague on details.

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider.  Firstly, how much data do you have?  MySQL isn't designed to be an analytics database.  If you have a "small amount" of data, then it doesn't matter.  However, if you grow or plan to grow, you may want to copy the data over to an analytic database such as Infobright.  Infobright does have an open-source option.

On top of the database, you have a few open-source BI solutions that will work very well.  Take a look at Pentaho, Jaspersoft, and Actuate/BIRT.  Actuate has some great drill down options, and they also have a way to easily get this data to a mobile device.

Full disclosure: I am the open-source guy for Infobright.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To make this clearer I'd like to point out that I am a manager and I am doing some research on behalf of our developers and management ourselves. I do have some coding experience however so I am interested to hear more about how you differentiate between a analytics database and something like a MySQL database? Our developers have not used these kind of packages before so we are coming into this completely new. We have a custom CRM system into which we wish to integrate better reporting ability. Any recommendations for how to go about this are very welcome.

Comment: Hey James, MySQL is a fantastic transactional database.  You would not want to use Infobright (or any other column-oriented rdbms) as a transactional database.  Likewise, you would not want to use MySQL as an analytic database.  MySQL is designed to do single row inserts/updates/deletes quickly and effectively.  Infobright is designed to find trends in the entire data set (such as sum, count, min, max, etc.).  Then, there's the whole nosql discussion.  I blogged about the 'emerging database landscape' and a recent whitepaper here: [link](http://bit.ly/nXqaZJ)

Answer (score 0):

In my research I discovered the following site which seems to be a good place to start for anyone looking at this topic:

[Dashboard Insight](http://www.dashboardinsight.com/)

This site includes a long list of available suites and tools.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently using Dundas Dashboard and have had a lot of success with it.  I am pretty sure it has a data source connector for mySQL, you just have to install a driver that they have available on their site.

All in all, great product, a little bit of a learning curve, but we've had a lot of success with it.